# how to find average and display average in star symbols in php

Tags: php

**data**

```
RATE_FEED_ID, RATE_FEED_VALUE, RATE_FEED_STATUS, DATE      RATE_FEED_TYPE  
 1                   3                Active       -              1  
 1.                 5                 Active       -              1   
 2.                 1                 Active       -              1  
 3.                 2                 Active       -              1     
 4.                 3                  "           -              1
```

i want Average of RATE_FEED_VALUE and i want to display average in star format

**code**

```
<?php
//RATING AVERAGE COUNT
$star="SELECT  SUM(RATE_FEED_VALUE) from FEEDBACK_RATING WHERE (RATE_FEED_TYPE='1') AND EMPLOYEE_ID='".$row["EMPLOYEE_ID"]."'";
$query = mysql_query($star); 
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($query)){                  
    $r= $data['RATE_FEED_VALUE'];
}

?>
```

Comment: Please format your database structure.

Comment: Check out the answers at this [thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Comment: If i get this right, you want to display 5 stars if the RATE_FEED_VALUE is 5? And 3 for RATE_FEED_VALUE = 3? You could use a simple for loop with the use of variable $r?

Comment: yes..i want to find first average and display stars of average

Comment: data+code formatting, removed screaming caps